# Why is the variable set to echo is off?

Tags: batch-file

why i get this output "Echo is off"
when i enter "test" in the variable userpw1 should hold it but it's just displays ECHO is OFF and the if statement wont work

```
@echo off
cls
set /p userid1=

::----- user password -----
:liuserpw
cls
color 0a
echo =======================================
echo   Hi       
echo =======================================
echo.
echo ====    Now enter your Password    ====
echo.
set /p %userpw1%=
set /p userpw2=<Users\password\%userid1%.txt
echo Loading file    [OK]
echo File response [%userpw2%]
echo %userid1%
echo %userpw1% :: Here it displayes ECHO is OFF
echo.
pause
if %userpw1% == %userpw2% goto 2

:2
echo this is now working
pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mistyped

```
set /p %userpw1%=
```

should be

```
set /p userpw1=
```

Then `echo %userpw1%` is equivalent to `echo` (with no params)

Comment: Well thanks! my bad sometimes i don't see som simple signs.